# Roll-up Summary field | OR filter criteria

Tags: roll-up-summary

I have a Roll-Up Summary (SUM Opportunity Product) field. The field gives an option to `Only records meeting certain criteria should be included in the calculation` which is really good because it allows me to filter but the filter criteria only has `AND` option but not an `OR`. Why is that? And how can I workaround  it? Please assist.

Comment: "Why is that?" Because they didn't want to make the engine overly complicated.

Comment: why not just put a formula field on the detail that includes the OR logic and then your filter just is `myFormula__c = true`

Comment: @cropredy Rollup fields do not show formula fields.

Comment: @apz They do show up BUT they cannot be cross object formulas

Answer (score 2):

there is posibilty to choose more than one option in a row in a value field, just pick two or more quadrats.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways to work around this limitation.

One option, using native functionality, is to decompose your `OR` Roll-Up Summary into more than one Roll-Up Summary, each of which has only a single criterion, and then using a separate formula field to sum those component Roll-Up Summaries. The downside to this approach, of course, is that you consume more of your scarce limit for Roll-Up Summaries.

Another option would be to use Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries, which (belying its name) can also work on master-detail relationships and which supports the full breadth of SOQL in defining the set of records to be included in the rollup.

Comment: DLRS is exactly what I recommend whenever you need something more complicated than the out-of-the-box feature, which is pretty common given its limitations.

Comment: Same here - unfortunately some orgs are extremely reluctant to install packages and/or are in Apex limit trouble.